# r- replace value variable in loop

Tags: r, loops, variables, replace

I need to print a value variable inside a loop. I'm using bquote but not getting the desired result.
My code is:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y<-x**2

nombre<-list('improve', 'maintain', 'worsen')
for (i in 1:3) {
aa<-nombre[i]
print(aa)
foo <- paste0(as.character(bquote( ~.(aa))),collapse='')
  print(foo)
plot(x,y)
mtext(foo)

}
```

I need to use the values stored in foo for a mtext from a graph.  So I'd need to print in mtext 'improve' in the 1st loop, 'maintain' in the 2nd and 'worsen' in the 3rd. But I get "list("improve")",
What is that bquote exactly do? Is there any other way to solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you want to be printed?

Comment: You could try  `for (i in 1:3) { print(nombre[[i]][1]) }`. I'm not sure I understand why you use paste and as.character etc. if you only want to print those values in nombre. (similar: `sapply(nombre, `[`, 1)`)

Comment: You can just use `print(nombre)` and print all 3, or `sapply(nombre, print)`

Answer (score 0):

To print all three as a vector, you could use

```
sapply(nombre, function(x) { x})
```

Other answers in the comments might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be:

```
nombre<-list('improve', 'maintain', 'worsen')
for (i in 1:3) {
aa<-nombre[i]
print(aa)
foo <- paste0(as.character(bquote( .(aa))),collapse='')
print(foo)
plot(x,y)
mtext(foo)
}
```

What I still don't know is what does this ~ do?